# Mocking a property that uses index

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I tried to decouple `ConfigurationManager` so I could mock it.

Here is my class and interface

```
public class Settings
{
    public string this[string index] => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[index];
}

public class ConfigurationRepository : IConfigurationRepository
{    
    public virtual Settings AppSettings
    {
        get { return new Settings(); }
    }
}

public interface IConfigurationRepository
{
   Settings AppSettings { get; }
}
```

Here is how I mock it

```
_configurationManager = new Mock<IConfigurationRepository>();
_configurationManager.SetupGet(m => m.AppSettings["someKey"]).Returns("someResult");
```

But when I try to test it I get an exception

> Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: m => m.AppSettings["someKey"]

And the test fails, it doesn't even go past my `Setup` method.

And I have no idea why I get this exception, could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That indexer property on the concrete `Settings` class would need to be `virtual` for Moq to be able to override its default behavior

```
public class Settings {
    public virtual string this[string index] => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[index];
}
```

I would also suggest refactoring the repository implementation to avoid initializing  the class every time the `AppSettings` property is called.

```
public class ConfigurationRepository : IConfigurationRepository {
    private Lazy<Settings> settings = new Lazy<Settings>(() => new Settings());

    public virtual Settings AppSettings {
        get { return settings.Value; }
    }
}
```